# Can we get all the actions from all blocks?

Tags: transactions, action, blocks, inline-action

Somebody say we can get all the blocks through rpc, then we can get all the actions.

But I found that in the block information, there're no inline actions, so many inline actions will lose, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the inline actions in `get_actions` RPC History API endpoint or inside the details of a transaction using also the RPC API `get_transaction`.

So that's exactly what I'm doing in that `eos-node-watcher`, I filter all the transactions relevant to my dapp and call `get_transaction` for them. The thing is that you could just shortcut it by running `get_actions` endpoint.

But after that if you want real-time integration I think you need to watch block by block indeed.

Comment: since the get_transaction is history api, we must store all history data to memory(use --filter-on=*), right?

Comment: if you need all of the transactions, contracts etc yes. otherwise you could just filter your dapp transactions

Comment: so there're no other way to get all the transactions except that use history plugin with filter-on = *, right? Even if we just want to get some transactions, we still need use the history plugin, because the transaction details is in the history.